# Bash - Count number of occurences in textfile and display in descending order

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line

I want to count the amount of the same words in a text file and display them in descending order.
So far I have :

```
    cat sample.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Which is mostly giving me satisfying output except the fact that it includes special characters like commas, full stops, ! and hyphen.

How can I modify existing command to not include special characters mentioned above?

Comment: Use `tr -d` to delete the special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tr` with a composite string of the letters you wish to delete.

Example:

```
$ echo "abc, def. ghi! boss-man" | tr -d ',.!'
abc def ghi boss-man
```

Or, use a POSIX character class knowing that `boss-man` for example would become `bossman`:

```
$ echo "abc, def. ghi! boss-man" | tr -d [:punct:]
abc def ghi bossman
```

---

Side note: You can have a lot more control and speed by using `awk` for this:

```
$ echo "one two one! one. oneone
two two three two-one    three" | 
 awk 'BEGIN{RS="[^[:alpha:]]"} 
     /[[:alpha:]]/ {seen[$1]++} 
     END{for (e in seen) print seen[e], e}' | 
 sort -k1,1nr -k2,2
4 one
4 two
2 three
1 oneone
```

Comment: I like the solution with tr -d [:punct:]. Thanks.

Comment: Im getting the output I've wanted but when I run the command the hyphen is still being counted as invisible field? Say I got occurrences such as 8 potatoes 5 potato 3 (it counts the hyphen but you can't see it) in the command line

Answer (score 0):

How about first extracting words with `grep`:

```
grep -o "\w\+" sample.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```